# Save ssh output to a variable

Tags: bash

I'm a bash scripting newb that is trying to write a script to retrieve ospf neighbors from routers that don't support that through snmp.  The following script works:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm ./results.txt

sshpass -f pfile ssh -T admin@192.168.128.47 > results.txt <<"ENDSSH"
show ip route ospf neighbor
exit
ENDSSH
```

Rather than put the results in a text file I would like them to be in a variable so I can parse the results.  I've tried the following to no avail:

```
MYVAR=$(sshpass -f pfile ssh -T admin@192.168.128.47 <<"ENDSSH"
show ip route ospf neighbor
exit
ENDSSH)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried it all on one line?  `MYVAR=$(sshpass -f pfile ssh -T admin@192.168.128.47 <<"ENDSSH"; show ip route ospf neighbor; exit; ENDSSH;)`

Answer (score 5):

The line to end the here document has to be exactly `ENDSSH`, nothing else.

```
MYVAR=$(sshpass -f pfile ssh -T admin@192.168.128.47 <<"ENDSSH"
show ip route ospf neighbor
exit
ENDSSH
)
```

Still, I see no need for `-T` and no need for a here document, but maybe it's needed by the router. I would also use a lower case variable -- upper case variables are for exported variables.

```
myvar=$(sshpass -f pfile ssh admin@192.168.128.47 show ip route ospf neighbor)
```

Comment: Thanks, moving the parentheses did the trick.  FWIW the -T is required with a Moxa router.  I also couldn't use your second suggestion because without the "exit" command the router just kept the connection open until the five minute timeout.